# How to handle passing runtime-sized arrays between classes in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

Right now I have a simple class that handles the parsing of XML files into ints that are useful to me. Looks something like this:

```
int* DataParser::getInts(){
    *objectNumbers = new int[getSize()];
    for (int i=0;i<getSize();i++){
            objectNumbers[i]=activeNode->GetNextChild()->GetContent();
    }
    return objectNumbers;
 }
```

In the main part of the program, I receive this by doing:

```
int* numbers= data->getInts();
///Do things to numbers[]
delete numbers;
```

Everything works fine until the delete command, which crashes everything. What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you are not pairing new[] with delete[].  This probably isn't the root of your bug here but you should get in the habbit of doing this.

The bug is almost certainly related to the code that you left commented out.  Can you add some more context there so we can see what you're doing with the numbers value?

In general, I find it's **much** easier to use a vector for this type of problem.  It takes the memory management out of the equation and has the added benefit of storing the size with the dynamic memory.

```
void DataParser::getInts(std::vector<int>& objectNumbers){
    for (int i=0;i<getSize();i++){
      objectNumbers.push_back(activeNode->GetNextChild()->GetContent());
    }
 }

...
std::vector<int> numbers;
data.getInts(numbers);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to

```
delete [] numbers;
```

The rules is whenever you

```
ptr = new Type[...];
```

make sure you

```
delete [] ptr;
```

instead of the regular

```
delete ptr;
```

which will result in undefined behavior (thanks Neil Butterworth) and is intended for deletion of a single instance where ptr points, not an array.

Comment: Actually, it may well not "work" at all - it gives what the C++ Standard calls "undefined behaviour".

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to communicate what the semantics of delete ptr; were, but its good to include that its undefined behavior. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following line:

```
 *objectNumbers = new int[getSize()];
```

What does it do? If you are returning `objectNumbers`, this is a pointer to `int`, and you should really be doing:

```
 objectNumbers = new int[getSize()];
```

Anyway, C++ gives you collections (`vector`, `list` etc) -- I'd have used one of those instead of a plain array. As noted elsewhere it is important to match your `new` with a `delete` and a `new []` with a `delete []`.

Passing arrays around isn't good design -- you are making the implementation public. Try to pass iterators to the begining and end of the array/collection/sequence of `int`s instead following the STL design.

Answer (score 2):

simply use a std::vector instead;

```
std::vector<int> DataParser::getInts(){
    std::vector<int> objectNumbers(getSize());
    for (int i=0;i<getSize();i++){
            objectNumbers[i]=activeNode->GetNextChild()->GetContent();
    }
    return objectNumbers;
 }
```

Comment: This code would result in a copy of the vector content on return. Probably more than once.  The example of JaredPar is the right way to do it. Pass the vector by reference and fill it in getInts.

Comment: Not necessarily, this code will typically benefit of return value optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

You will quickly run into trouble and maintenance issues. Consider using std::vector, this is the proper way to do it.